# Replacing the string content in a List of an object in Java

Tags: java, string, list

I'm having some problems with replacing `String` field's content in a `List` member.

I have a List of objects and one of the fields inside that list is `String`. So as an example I have the following with getters and setters.

```
public class MyObject {
  private String message;
  private int numbers;
...
```

Let's assume I've created a list of `MyObject` and there are 3 of them in that list and I've added values to them from somewhere external like a database.

```
List<MyObject> myObject = new ArrayList<>();
```

The problem lies in that String message. Let's say the `String` field in the first 3 entries equals as the following.

```
"First message"
"Second message"
"Third message"
```

How can I iterate through the List of `myObject`'s `String` message field and replace the alphabetical content `"First"` with new content such as "1st" and so on and so forth.

Comment: Create an array of strings of 1st, 2nd, 3rd.. and in parallel iterate through them while exchanging strings

Comment: Would you post an [MCVE] ?

Comment: Do you have a collection of the substitution you want to make? Are you planning on replacing all ordinals?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could only do that if your class MyObject allows you to update its internal string; for example by providing a setter method.

In other words:

1. you iterate your list of MyObject objects
2. for each of that objects, you have to query its message
3. then you would have to call a setter to update its content

Answer (score 1):

You can use an Iterator. But your list has to be String type.

**Example**

```
ArrayList<String> myObject = new ArrayList<>();
ListIterator litr = myObject.listIterator();
  while(litr.hasNext()) {
     String element = litr.next();
     if(element.equalsTo("first message"))
        element = "1st message";
       litr.set(element);
  }
```

Hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

You should create an `array` that would look as it follows:

```
String[] s = new String[10];
s[0] = "th";
s[1] = "st";
s[2] = "nd";
s[3] = "rd";
s[4] = "th";
s[5] = "th";
s[6] = "th";
s[7] = "th";
s[8] = "th";
s[9] = "th";
```

Now it's enough to loop through your list and replace first word in `String` field `message` with current index `i` appended with `s[i%10]`.